# Как записать результат выполнения $map в файл?

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<?php
$cache_ttl = 900; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_airlines = "http://*******/tmp/airlines.data";
$cache_file_products = "http://*******/tmp/products.data";


$map = function ($array, $from, $to)
{
    $result = [];
    if (!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from] ? : null;
            $value = $element[$to] ? : null;
            if ($key && $value) {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};

if (file_exists($cache_file_airlines) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_airlines)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents($cache_file_airlines);
} else {
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents('http://*********/json/airlines.json');
    file_put_contents($cache_file_airlines, $get_airlines);
}
$airlines = $map(json_decode($get_airlines, true), 'iata', 'name');



if (file_exists($cache_file_products) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_products)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $response = file_get_contents($cache_file_products);
} else {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/calendar?currency=RUB&origin=MOW&destination=AER&token=***********");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *******"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($cache_file_products, $response);
}

$products = json_decode($response, true);
$replace_value = function ($key, $val)use ($airlines)
{
    $response = $val;
    switch ($key) {
            case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}?>









 <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Дата вылета</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Обратная дата</th>
 <th style="text-align: center;">Цена, р.</th> 
        <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;"> Авиакомпания</th>
<th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>    <tbody>
<?php
if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
?>
<tr><td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
<td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $replace_value('price', $row['price']); ?>&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td>
 <td class="mob"><img height="50" alt="" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png" /></td>


      <td><a rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" title="Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" href="https://*****.com/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=<?=$key?>&depart_date=<?=substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)?>&return_date=<?=substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a></td></tr>
<?php
}
}
}
}
?>  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Как записать результат выполнения  $map в файл, чтобы постоянно не выполнять ее. На примере кода. Спасибо

Comment: В чем отличие этого вопроса от этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749580/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-api?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу вытащить данные из Api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749580/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
$log = fopen("test.txt","w+"); 

fwrite($log,"текст для записи"); 

fclose($log);
```

Comment: А еще можно записать результат от serialize($map) если не хотите возиться с форматами данных.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Мне бы кэшированием

Comment: Каким кэшированием, о чем вы? Сформулируйте сначала проблему, что именно вы хотите решить.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov постоянно выполняется $map

Comment: Перенесите вызов $map и сделайте обработку данных и уже после сохраняйте в файл - как я уже советовал, проще сделать file_put_contents('results.data', serialize($map(json_decode($get_airlines, true), 'iata', 'name'))). Из него же потом читайте для кэширования прямо в $airlines = unserialize(file_get_contents('results.data'))

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Даниэль у меня не получится, вы можете показать на примере моего кода? С уважением.